# how to resolve not found type declarations error while using Underscore with typescript

Tags: typescript, underscore.js

I try to use the modular import from the [underscore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/underscore) in a typescript app like this:

`import map from 'underscore/modules/map'`

It works and does the job, but cause the below error:

> Cannot find module 'underscore/modules/map' or its corresponding type declarations.ts

This is the [related Codesand](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-moser-efciu8?file=/src/App.tsx)

Any idea how to resolve the error?

Comment: GitHub issue, with answer: https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/2975

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave roughly the following answer in the [issue ticket](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/2975).

The problem is in `@types/underscore/package.json`, which forbids TypeScript from importing anything other than the monolithic version of the package (`exports` field):

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/6b20b068e23eaa009323347f248d02f05c609afe/types/underscore/package.json

Contrast this with Underscore's own `package.json`, which does allow module imports:

https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/1.13.6/package.json

The *best* solution is to report a bug to DefinitelyTyped, or to submit a pull request there with your own fix (if you have the patience and courage to work on that).

The *easiest* solution is to just use the monolithic interface; it's only 8 kB. Second easiest is to put a `// @ts-ignore` above the import, but this has the disadvantage that TS will not check the type of any function that you import the modular way:

```
// @ts-ignore
import map from 'underscore/modules/map';
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

image on npm means the package does not contain typings, but there are typings on `@types/underscore` instead

Make sure you have `@types/underscore` package installed

Comment: I also installed the `@types/underscore` but it does not change anything. Also, it's fine with monolithic import, the only problem is when you want to use modular import